# Healthcheck in ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

`ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter.java` global filter is getting called while I am loading my spring-gateway client.Is there anyway I can inject `HealthCheckServiceInstanceListSupplier` to the above global filter so that a health check will happened before it sends the request?

What I want to achieve ?
I want a health check before LoadBalancer send a request to service in my spring-gateway project.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Spring cloud team @OlgaMaciaszek

Yes, it will use the ReactorLoadBalancer bean that it finds. So you need to have an instance set up in your config that will use that particular ServiceInstanceListSupplier implementation. 
There's an [example](http://%20https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-commons/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#instance-health-check-for-loadbalancer) of such custom config here.